# Preload fancybox images iframe with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I have an `iframe` that holds a gallery. In my main webpage I have an image and when clicked, it opens "that" iframe with fancybox.

**The code is like this:**

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe popup" href="http://tambooflores.com.mx/iframe_colores.html" height="100%" width="100%" > 

some IMAGE here
</a>
```

**The script for fancybox is:**

```
 $('.fancybox').fancybox();

    $("a.popup").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick' : true,
        'width' : 676,
        'height' : 630,
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'padding' : 16,
        'onComplete' : function() {
            $('#fancybox-frame').load(function() { // wait for frame to load and then gets it's height

            $('#fancybox-content').height($(this).contents().find('body').height()+30);
        });
    }
    });
```

The issue is that I have 8 iframes with 8 different galleries (with 20 images each). When I click any of them, it is taking so long to show.

So I was thinking to load maybe half of the images when loading the main web page.

I was also thinking of adding this in each iframe:

```
The content of IFrame
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
   fireOnReadyEvent();
   parent.IFrameLoaded();
//]]>
</script>
```

Please take a [look at the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JyxSt/) 
 1. How to minor time of loading?
 2. How to improve loading or how to load half of images in load function?

Comment: It is a php project that includes these javascripts? is that the case I have some tips that I could share with you.

Comment: well, I use php but not in this particular issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I resolved in this way:

Get the image sizes (height or width) that is going to load and put this result variable as a div height or width value. And that's all.

Comment: could you please show an example, is it with jquery in onload function?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand very well your question. Sorry. Facebook load images in low resolution an the replace them for the original. Check this link: https://github.com/ronnyandre/jQuery-High-Resolution-Image-Loader